# Get the number of links in a link list in Shopify Liquid

Tags: shopify, e-commerce, liquid

In Shopify Liquid, how can I get the number of links within a link list for use in an `if` statement? For instance:

```
if [[ the count of `linklist.links` ]] > 6
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Joe!  Please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on improving your question.  As @kenorb has stated you are unlikely to get a helpful response when requesting a binary response, and I suspect that you actually want a more detailed answer.

Comment: Guys, can you stop being robots and act like humans for a second? It's abundantly clear what the questioner is asking for.

Answer (score 4):

Both [`linklist.links`](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects#linklist) and [`link.links`](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects#link) return an array. So you can use the [`size`](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/filters#size) filter to get the number of links in your menu. You can use the **dot notation** of this filter in an `if` statement:

```
if linklist.links.size > 6
```